# PC fails to turn on when I connect 8 pin atx

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

My PC fails to turn on when I connect the 8 pin ATX 12v. I can hear a whine from the PSU when it wont turn on, the fans do not spin at all.

I can get it to start when I have the graphics card connected, 1 RAM stick, and the 24 pin ATX. I'm not sure where to go from here, it seems to me like the mobo is dead.

mobo is 970 Pro3 R2.0 ASRock.

## Update

I just tested with a brand new PSU and the same problem happens. Once I connect the 8 pin and try to start it it wont start even with the 8 pin removed. I have to remove and reattach the 24 pin again to get it to start.

Comment: Are you able to provide the make and model of your motherboard?

Comment: @Burgi updated question

Comment: May be I don't understand the question, but why do you think the motherboard is dead if the PC starts with various things connected? Or do you feel the issue is  with a circuit on the board?

Comment: @Dave It fails to start when the cpu is powered via the 8 pin connector. I'm lookng for more trouble shooting/help before I buy anything. I can't see how the CPU can fail (probably just my inexperience), so I am assuming it's the mobo.

Comment: Oh I've had a CPU fail. It is rare but it does happen...

Comment: I am not sure i understand what your question is.

Comment: Why do you need the 8 pin? What is the 8 pin? Are you saying without the 8 pin it works?

Comment: @Dave The 8 pin ATX powers the CPU. When it is not connected the PC turns on (no POST). I believe then it is either the mobo or the cpu which has failed. I have come here seeking more troubleshooting options to find out which one is definitively defective.

Comment: But are you saying it powers when the 8 pin is not connected?